# My page is not opening after receiving a push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic3

In my ionic app, I need to open a specific page after receiving a push notification.

I'm testing it in the Android Studio emulator and have displayed a bunch of console logs that prove that the push.on('notification').subscribe event is definitely triggering the page using navCtrl.push (I've tried navCtrl.setRoot too) and the ngOnInit is doing everything as normal and making it to the end of its code.

The problem is that after that, the page just isn't showing.

I can see the following message in the Android console log, but I don't really know what it means:

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: ng:///AppModule/ShiftDetailsPage.ngfactory.js: Line 563 : ERROR
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(563)] "ERROR", source: ng:///AppModule/ShiftDetailsPage.ngfactory.js (563)
```

but they appear before all the console log messages output by ngOnInit in ShiftDetailsPage, so I guess they don't mean there was a problem loading the page.

Another thing that is appearing is:

```
Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined.
```

in the app.

I've searched everywhere for someone having a similar problem, but all I can find are descriptions of how to receive notifications, but nothing helpful about how to trigger pages from the event.

Should I use something other than navCtrl.push or is that the correct way?

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Here's the code in the push.on subscribe:

```
push.on('notification').subscribe(async (data: EventResponse) => {
  console.log("in notification, data = " + JSON.stringify(data));
  if (data.additionalData.shiftId != null
  &&  data.additionalData.shiftId != ""
  &&  await this.login.isLoggedIn()
    ) {
    console.log("in notification, shiftId = " + data.additionalData.shiftId);
    console.log("in notification, isLoggedIn = " + JSON.stringify(await this.login.isLoggedIn()));
    const confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Shift Notification',
      message: data.additionalData.shiftId,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ignore',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'View',
          handler: () => {
            console.log("in notification, handler");
            this.shiftDetailsProvider.getShiftDetails(data.additionalData.shiftId).then( async shift => {
              const userLocation = await this.getUserLocation().then(userLocation => {
                console.log("in pushSetup on notification, userLocation = ", userLocation);
                return userLocation;
              });
              this.navCtrl.push(ShiftDetailsPage, {shift: shift, userLocation: userLocation, sourcePage: "notification"});
            });
          }
        },
      ]
    });

    confirmAlert.present();

  } else {
    console.log("in notification, else");
    if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
      console.log("in notification, foreground");
      const confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Notification',
        message: data.message,
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel'
          },
          {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('New notification callback')
            }
          },
        ]
      });

      confirmAlert.present();

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        console.log("in notification, platform is ios");
        push.finish(data.additionalData.notId);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Push notification clicked from the background');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Agreed - please share some code for your subscription to `onNotificationOpen`, and where you are doing this subscription (ideally inside a `platform.ready()`.

Comment: which plugin did you use for push notification? can you post your code?

Comment: Please share your code.so,we can see what's your exact problem is, thank you.

Comment: I've just added my code for the push.on subscribe event. Any thoughts would be welcomed.